# NPM, NVM, NodeJS on WSL2 Ubuntu

Tags: nodejs, npm

Before I you read my question, please let me know if WSL2 Ubuntu related questions are permitted in this forum.

I have a Laravel App on Ubuntu WSL2. I am trying to add SCSS/SASS with it.

I already have installed NVM (Recommended to use for Linux-based distros) and both have the latest versions of Nodejs and NPM.

When I'm inside my Laravel App folder, I use `npm install` but I receive these errors:

> npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM
> npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
> npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    darwin
> npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  undefined
> npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   linux
> npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/username/.npm/_logs/2020-12-04T03_43_34_210Z-debug.log

I have tried reinstalling nodejs and npm by purging them from the Ubuntu OS, and as well as removing $PATH on my local Windows PATH Environment.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

This line is telling..

`npm ERR! notsup Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin"}`

Was your laravel app developed in a macOS environment previously? You have a dependency (fsevents) that can only be run in macOS. Check your package.json and package-lock.json to figure out whats using fsevents and see if you can remove that dependency.

Comment: I was able to solve my issue by creating a new laravel application. Not so sure why my previous application was having these issues. And no, I did my development in WSL 2 Ubuntu!

Comment: Hmm very weird! Glad you were able to figure it out though.